# UIActivityIndicatorView always crashes

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

My UIActivityIndicatorView always crashes my app.
When I press my download button, the indicator shows and starts spinning.
But when I stop it, I just have to touch the screen somewhere and my app crashes.

### .h

```
@interface DownloadViewController : UIViewController < FinishedParsing, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate > 
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView* indicator;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView* indicator;

- (void)initSpinner;
- (void)spinBegin;
- (void)spinEnd;
```

### .m

```
@implementation DownloadViewController

@synthesize indicator;

- (IBAction)download:(id)sender 
{
    [self initSpinner];
    [self spinBegin];

    [OJSGatewayCommunicationService parseArticles :self];
}

- (void)initSpinner 
{
    self.indicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge]autorelease];    

    // we put our spinning "thing" right in the center of the current view
    CGPoint newCenter = (CGPoint) [self.view center];
    indicator.center = newCenter;   
    [self.view addSubview:indicator];   
}

- (void)spinBegin 
{
    [indicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)spinEnd 
{
    self.indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[indicator stopAnimating];
    indicator.hidden = TRUE;
    [indicator removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void) fetchPDF:(NSMutableArray *)chapters
{
    [self spinEnd];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that in your `initSpinner` method you are accessing the `indicator` ivar directly (`indicator = ...`), not through the property mutator (`self.indicator = ...`), so the indicator is not getting retained.

Comment: In your edited version of the code you are now over-retaining and leaking the activity indicator because you use the property (`self.indicator = ...`) but you don't autorelease it anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead or autoreleasing it, take control of it and release it manually by calling self.indicated = nil after you're done with it and release it in dealloc.
That way, you're sure it won't vanish without warnings...

Comment: Thank you, it does not crash anymore! But my indicator also doesn't stop animating...

Comment: Also remove it from the view in your spinEnd method.

Answer (score 1):

In your function:

```
- (void)spinEnd {
    [indicator stopAnimating];
    self.indicator = nil;
}
```

I would suggest not setting the indicator to nil. Indeed, setting `self.indicator = nil` will make the indicator be released. If this also triggers deallocation, it is possible that the UI will not be in a condition to redraw itself correctly when the main loop is executed. Notice: this is just an hypothesis I am making due to the strange behavior you are having. It may work or it may not.

I would also make sure that `hidesWhenStopped` is set to `YES` when the indicator is stopped. All in all, I would rewrite:

```
- (void)spinEnd {
    self.indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES; //-- additional guarantee, but it should already be set
    [indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

and release `indicator` in your `-dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    ....
    [_indicator release];
    _indicator = nil;
    ...
    [super dealloc];
}
```

By the way, also fix the memory leak you have in `initSpinner`:

```
- (void)initSpinner {
    self.indicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge] autorelease];    
    ....
```

It is to be noted that, when you execute `initSpinner`, if an `indicator` was already there, assigning a new `UIActivityIndicatorView` to `self.indicator` will make the previous one to be released.

EDIT:

If none of the above haw worked, you could try two more things:

1. setting the indicator `hidden` property to YES in `-spinEnd`;
2. possibly I was wrong, but it occurs to me that setting `self.indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES` could be more effective before calling `[indicator stopAnimating];`

Comment: Well, my first version was with autorelease, and it crashed my app everytime.

Comment: Sorry, this version with self.indicator works with autorelease. But the problem with a not stopping indicator still exists.

Comment: @madmax: please see my edit, I came up with another suggestion. Hope it helps. About the autorelease thing: in your first version of the code, you were autoreleasing and assigning directly to the ivar; now you are using the property, which retains the object for you.

Comment: No,also no help. I do this in spinEnd -> self.indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
 [indicator stopAnimating];
    indicator.hidden = TRUE;
    [indicator removeFromSuperview];   How can it be so difficult to just hide a view?

Comment: yes, I don't understand this either... have you checked that spinEnd is actually called and the self.indicator is not nil there? I don't know what else to think of...

Comment: Yes, it gets called but nothing happens. Maybe i try to make a whole new view controller only for this indicator...